# How to pipe two separate outputs of ffmpeg to separate programs?

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, multipleoutputs

I am running a ffmpeg command which takes a single video input (h.264) and 1) outputs a screen grab every 5 seconds and 2) transcodes the original video to a different bitrate/profile/etc.

I would like to pipe the output of each operation to a separate program.  Currently, I can pipe the *last* output to a program by adding a trailing 'dash' (-) at the end of the command.

However, I can't figure out how to pipe *both* outputs to different programs simultaneously.  Any help appreciated.

Example command which pipes the last input to another program:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -r 1/5 test%03d.jpg -vcodec h264_omx -r 8 -b:v 512k - | ./myprogram
```

Comment: This actually helps: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1663

Comment: Another discussion of sockets: https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-May/036112.html

Comment: None of the answer above helps anything